# Pre requisites for Windows Vista Service Pack 2 (SP2)

Tags: windows-vista, installation, windows-installation, service-pack

I am trying to install Windows Vista Service Pack 2.

Currently, I have Service Pack 1 . Before installation, I disable to Antivirus program as suggested by Windows Vista Site.

I have tried several times and always run into this error

[image]

For all I know, I have a file `C:\Windows\System32\wscntfy.dll`

Some approach suggest deleting this file.So Service Pack2 can automatically create a new one. Even though I am the admin, I am unable to change access permissions to the folder.

I remember, I had once installed Service Pack 2 before ( That harddisk crashed and my recovery discs have Windows Vista Basic). I can't recall exactly but maybe there were some versions of certain software to be installed. I have googled but I can't find any link for that information.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: the error is STATUS_FILE_IDENTITY_NOT_PERSISTENT . Run **sfc /scannow** before installing the Sp2.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have tried doing *sfc /scannow* before another attempt at installation. *sfc* scan shows that all files are proper but when I try to install SP2 again, I run into the same issue

Comment: upload the folder **C:\Windows\logs\CBS** and the file **C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log**

Comment: Did you try using the [System Update Readiness tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821/en-us) already?